# Byte Array conversion to string

Tags: go

My intent is to read a text file , and print records on console  . Sample text file format

abc 123

test zzz

hello world

I am using byte array to initialize my structure . 
However when I try to print after splitting the read lines , blank values are printed for the second token which is obtained after the split

```
  package main 


import (
"fmt"
"bufio"
"os"
"strings"
"io/ioutil"
)

type person struct {
    fName [20]byte
    lName [20]byte
}

func main(){

reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)

fmt.Printf("Enter Name ")
fname, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
fname = strings.Replace(fname, "\n", "", -1)
fname = strings.Replace(fname, "\r", "", -1)

readFile, err := ioutil.ReadFile(fname)
 if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

s := string(readFile)
fileTextLines := strings.Split(s, "\n")



sli := make([]person, len(fileTextLines))
    for _, eachline := range fileTextLines {
        res1 := strings.Split( eachline, " ")

        var fname [20]byte  

        copy( fname[:], []byte(res1[0] ))
        fmt.Println(string(fname[:]))


        var lname [20]byte  
        copy( lname[:], []byte(res1[1] ) )
        fmt.Println(string(lname[:]))

        p := person{fname ,lname}
        sli = append(sli,p)
    }

// print the slice 

//   for _,object  := range sli {
//       fmt.Printf("First Name: %s Last Name: %s\n", string(object.fName[:]), string(object.lName[:]))
//    }

}
```

With the suggested approach I got the following output

```
                             Last Name: 123
                             Last Name: zzz
```

First Name: hello                Last Name: world

Comment: Can you add what output you got

Comment: @Eklavya I posted my output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you split the first name and last name there is some extra white spaces in the values, so I added **strings.TrimSpace** and below code is working now, and also you don't need to Initialize **sli** with fix length, append will automatically increase the size of slice.

```
package main 

import (
"fmt"
"bufio"
"os"
"strings"
"io/ioutil"
)

type person struct {
    fName [20]byte
    lName [20]byte
}

func main(){

reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)

fmt.Printf("Enter Name ")
fname, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
fname = strings.Replace(fname, "\n", "", -1)
fname = strings.Replace(fname, "\r", "", -1)

readFile, err := ioutil.ReadFile(fname)
 if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

s := string(readFile)
fileTextLines := strings.Split(s, "\n")



sli := []person{}
    for _, eachline := range fileTextLines {
        res1 := strings.Split( eachline, " ")

        var fname [20]byte  

        copy( fname[:], []byte(strings.TrimSpace(res1[0])))
        fmt.Println(string(fname[:]))


        var lname [20]byte  
        copy( lname[:], []byte(strings.TrimSpace(res1[1])) )
        fmt.Println(string(lname[:]))

        p := person{fname ,lname}
        sli = append(sli,p)
    }

// print the slice 

   for _,object  := range sli {
       fmt.Printf("First Name: %s Last Name: %s\n", string(object.fName[:]), string(object.lName[:]))
    }

}
```

Just found out that extra with space is carriage return **"\r"**, If you are using windows platform you should use below line to split the text with newline

```
strings.Split(strings.Replace(windows, "\r\n", "\n", -1), "\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
readFile, err := ioutil.ReadFile(fname)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

fileTextLines := bytes.Split(readFile, []byte("\n"))

sli := make([]person, 0, len(fileTextLines))
for _, eachline := range fileTextLines {
    res1 := bytes.Split(eachline, []byte(" "))
    if len(res1) < 2 {
        continue
    }
    var p person
    copy(p.fName[:], res1[0])
    copy(p.lName[:], res1[1])
    sli = append(sli, p)
}

for _, object := range sli {
    fmt.Printf("First Name: %s Last Name: %s\n", object.fName[:], object.lName[:])
}
```

This simplifies the code by working with []byte instead of string and handles case where line has only one token.

Working example on the GoLang PlayGround: https://play.golang.org/p/JFcM1uE3Ywm

Comment: thks for the help..Although your code works  with a byte created input file , the problem comes when there is a text input file and the output is distorted ...does it work if the user supplies a txt file ?